# When the class does not need to throw an Exception

Tags: java, exception

i made this code and it compiled correctly and i got (hello throwit  caught finally after)
but still don't know why the class `RTExcept` has not to throw `RuntimeException (public class RTExcept throws RuntimeException {})`

```
public class RTExcept {

public static void throwit(){
      System.out.print("throwit ");
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try{
    System.out.print("hello");
    throwit();
   } catch (Exception e){
   System.out.print("caught");
   } finally{
   System.out.print("finally");
   }
   System.out.print("after");
  }   
}
```

Comment: `RuntimeException` and any subclasses of it don't need to be specified in `throws`.

Comment: If a "checked" exception can occur in a method then either the method must use try/catch to suppress the possible exception or must announce the possibility of the exception via the `throws` clause on the method header.  But not all exceptions are in the "checked" category -- only Throwable classes that are subclasses of Exception but not subclasses of RuntimeException are "checked".

Comment: The spec for Exception says: *The class Exception and any subclasses that are not also subclasses of RuntimeException are checked exceptions. Checked exceptions need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.*

Comment: Classes don't throw exceptions. Methods throw sceptics.

Comment: @EJP Constructor ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has thrown a RuntimeException, but you "swallow" the exception by just printing out "caught".

You ignore the reference to the RuntimeException catch block. Append e.getClass() to your System.out like below and you will see the RuntimeExcetion.

```
 class RTExcept {
public static void throwit(){
    System.out.print("throwit ");
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        System.out.print("hello ");
        throwit();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(" caught " + e.getClass());
    } finally{
        System.out.print(" finally ");
    }
    System.out.print(" after ");
}
}
```

prints:
    hello throwit  caught class java.lang.RuntimeException finally  after

Comment: No problem :) But keep in mind the comments you got to your question. It is very important to be able to distinguish checked and unchecked exceptions.